# Difference between publish and restart in jboss/tomcat

Tags: spring, tomcat, jboss

What is difference between publish and restart in jboss/tomcat? I am really confused about when one should use restart or publish? 
Every time I make any change config in my Java(Spring) application(on localhost) I had to do a compile and then perform a restart of server so that it picks up the changes.
Is there any easier way to get the changes picked up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [JRebel](http://zeroturnaround.com/software/jrebel/) if you want to avoid redeploys. It fully supports Spring and you'll see changes immediately reflected in the deployed application. It's a commercial plugin but it saves you a lot of time.